# Edit video metadata tags of MP4 files

Tags: c#, metadata, taglib-sharp

I want to edit following video tags of MP4 files like **Title**, **Subtitle**, **Rating**, **Coment**, **Author**. I have search alot and find solution
*Taglib sharp*. But taglib sharp only edit title and comment. I also explore Directshow and UltraD3lib but my problem is 
still there. If anybody have example or any opensource library then please share with me.

Comment: @Brian Nickel need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple short methods I use to update my Video library files
Movie is a POCO object with the name, IMDB number, file name, year.. properties
ADOHelper is a class that I use to simplify ADO DB/SQL calls
With the code below I get the following icons on my videos

[image]

And when I look at the properties of the video I get the following

[image]

```
    private static void UpdateActors(Movie found, FileInfo movie)
    {
        var sql = $"SELECT n.primaryName FROM Principals p Inner join Names n on p.nconst = n.nconst where tconst = '{found.IMDB}'";
        var table = ADOHelper.ReturnDataTable(Conn, sql, CommandType.Text);
        var value = (from DataRow row in table.Rows select row[0].ToString()).ToList();
        var f = TagLib.File.Create(movie.FullName);
        f.Tag.Artists = value.ToArray();
        f.Tag.AlbumArtists = value.ToArray();
        f.Save();
    }

    private static string UpdateGenre(Movie found, FileInfo movie)
    {
        var returned = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var sql = $"SELECT Genre FROM TitleGenre where TitleId = '{found.IMDB}' order by sort";
            var table = ADOHelper.ReturnDataTable(Conn, sql, CommandType.Text);
            var f = TagLib.File.Create(movie.FullName);
            f.Tag.Genres = (from DataRow row in table.Rows select row[0].ToString()).ToArray();
            returned = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            f.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(found.FilePath + " : " + e.Message);
        }
        return returned;
    }

    private static int UpdateYear(Movie found, FileInfo movie)
    {
        var returned = 0;
        try
        {
            var f = TagLib.File.Create(movie.FullName);
            var sql = $"SELECT startYear FROM Titles where tconst = '{found.IMDB}'";
            var table = ADOHelper.ReturnDataTable(Conn, sql, CommandType.Text);
            f.Tag.Year = uint.Parse(table.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            returned = (int)f.Tag.Year;
            f.Tag.Title = found.Name;
            f.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(found.FilePath + " : " + e.Message);
        }
        return returned;
    }

    private static string UpdateName(Movie found, FileInfo movie, string description)
    {
        var returned = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var f = TagLib.File.Create(movie.FullName);
            f.Tag.Title = description;
            returned = description;
            f.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(found.FilePath + " : " + e.Message);
        }
        return returned;
    }

    private static void UpdatePicture(Movie found, FileInfo movie)
    {
        try
        {
            var poster = $"{PosterPath}\\{found.IMDB}.jpg";
            if (File.Exists(poster))
            {
                var f = TagLib.File.Create(movie.FullName);
                IPicture picture = new Picture(poster);
                f.Tag.Pictures = new[] { picture };
                f.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter("G:\\NeedPicture.txt", true))
                    writer.WriteLine($"{found.IMDB} : {found.Name} No Picture");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(found.FilePath + " : " + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps